# Git branch picker with dialog: escaping quotes

Tags: git, bash, dialog, xargs

I want to have a git branch picker for a shell script and ran into a problem with escaping quotes when passing the list to dialog with xargs.
Maybe someone can help me find and fix the issue?
I'm using the following command to create a dialog:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='"%(refname:short)" "%(authorname): %(contents:subject) (%(committerdate:relative))"'|xargs -p -d'\n' dialog --menu \"Select a branch\" 0 0 0
```

I get `Error: Expected 2 arguments, found only 1.` instead of a dialog.

Comment: Missing space here? `-d'\n'`

Comment: I believe it's not necessary.

Comment: Which part raises that error?

Comment: I suspect that %(contents:subject) which is a commit message has some single quotes or other characters which have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably being cheated by `xargs`s quoting.
I can make it work with GNU Parallel:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs --format='%(refname:short)
%(authorname): %(contents:subject) (%(committerdate:relative))' | parallel -r --tty -Xj1 dialog --menu \"Select a branch\" 0 0 0
```

Yes, there *is* a newline after 'short)'.

Comment: I saw that some use parallel instead of xargs but in my opinion its purpose is different to what I'm trying to achieve. In my case I just want to pass a bunch of strings as parameters to dialog which is what xargs is supposed to do.

Comment: @ska-uk As you mention in your comment your problem may be due to characters that need to be escaped for `xargs` do the right thing. GNU Parallel defaults to quote everything, so it ought to be easier to predict and give you fewer unexpected surprises. Anyway, I tried getting it to work with `xargs` and failed. Both will fail if you have a lot of options as you may hit the max line length for a shell command.